# How to make sure that Firefox uses old address-bar behavior?

Tags: firefox, address-bar

I remember that in the old version of Firefox I could type "google maps" in the address-bar and Firefox would navigate to `http://maps.google.com/`.

Since I upgraded to Firefox 8 I can't do this anymore. I must type "googlemaps" instead — no space between "google" and "maps".

Is there a way to make sure that Firefox returns to the old behavior, which I like better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling `google maps` from address bar brings me search result page in Firefox 8. However, you can try resetting tool-bars, search engines and preference to default:

[image]

Comment: It works! After reset all user preferences to Firefox defaults and installed Browse By Name addon : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browse-by-name/ I now get exactly what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @ITFan Resetting the preferences has dothing to do with it. You should write about an addon in a separate answer instead of accepting this one.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that `google` at the start of what you type in the adress bar is now considered as a special keyword indicating that Firefox should "google" whatever comes next. One way to get around it is to start with a different word. So

`maps google`

will work, as would

`google google maps`.

I don't know of a way to disable the new behaviour, however (nothing I found in Preferences or at `about:config` seems to deal with it)